# npm publish and version patch is causing a dependency loop, so if there's an error a manual bump is required, how to resolve this?

Tags: node.js, bash, jenkins, npm

I have an automated build, and part of the execute bash order is:

```
npm publish
//automated script runs here, if it succeeds:
npm version patch -m "blabla"
```

the problem is, if the script fails, the version isn't patched to a new one (and it shouldn't be), so if the errors are fixed, and I run this automated build again, I of course get an error since npm publish is trying to publish the same version. I'm not sure how to do a workaround for this.

I can't place the npm publish after the automated script, since it relies on the new version and build that it pulls from our npm repo.

Thanks!